# Why are there three fields in my image resolution?

Tags: linux, image, bmp, steganography

When analyzing my BMP image, I found that there are three fields in my resolution, ex. 960 x 540 x 32. Why is this happening?

I have a BMP file I am trying to run steganography software on. While trying to run, the software tells me that the bmp file's format is not accepted. I looked into it and ran file on the image and got this:

`output.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 98/2000 and newer format, 960 x 540 x 32, cbSize 2073738, bits offset 138`

As you can see, there are three fields in the resolution. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Please share how this problem is related to programming, or to steganography?

Comment: Maybe the third parameter is the number of colors within that file?

Answer (score 1):

The 32 would be the number of bits per pixel